# AngularJS: calculate total of price in nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to show a set of orders with all of its required data.

**AngularJS**

```
getorders = angular.module('getorders', []);
getorders.controller("allorders",function($scope,$http){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'orders').then(function (results) {
        $scope.orders = results.data;

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.orders.length; i++){
            var orders = $scope.orders[i];  
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="orderspresent" ng-cloak="">
 <div class="roworders" style="margin-bottom:5px;" ng-controller="allorders" >
  <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat= "o in orders | orderBy:'-orderDate'" ng-hide= "o.orderStatus=='done'">
    <div class="sm-st clearfix">
      <div class="sm-st-info">
         <span>{{o.customerName}}</span>
         <p>{{o.orderDate | date:'h:mm'}}</p> 
         <ul>
           <li ng-repeat= "details in o.details">
            {{details.aantal}} x {{details.productTitle}}
            <div ng-if="details.extras">
            +{{details.extras}} 
            </div>
            {{(details.productPrijs * details.aantal)+details.extrasPrice}}
            </li>     
            <p class="totalprice">{{getTotal()}} euro</p> 
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>             
     </div>
    </div>
```

**JSON SAMPLE**

```
  {
    "49": {
           "orderID": 49,
           "customerID": 61,
           "orderDate": "2015-05-06 10:03:05",
           "orderDeliveryDate": "2015-05-06",
           "orderStatus": "prepare",
           "customerName": "Caroline",
           "details": [
                       {
                         "orderdetailID": 83,
                         "productTitle": "Sexy Teacher",
                         "productPrijs": 4,
                         "aantal": 2,
                         "extras": "Extra syrup, Soya milk",
                         "extrasPrice": 0.6
                       },
                       {
                         "orderdetailID": 84,
                         "productTitle": "Caramel Macchiato",
                         "productPrijs": 5.2,
                         "aantal": 2,
                         "extras": false,
                         "extrasPrice": 0
                      },
                      {
                         "orderdetailID": 85,
                         "productTitle": "The Coach",
                         "productPrijs": 3,
                         "aantal": 3,
                         "extras": false,
                         "extrasPrice": 0
                     },
                     {
                        "orderdetailID": 86,
                        "productTitle": "The Virgin",
                        "productPrijs": 3.2,
                        "aantal": 5,
                        "extras": "Extra syrup, Whipped cream, 3 espresso shots",
                        "extrasPrice": 2.4
                     }
                    ]
                }
    }
```

For each order a couple of details are shown. And this works great but now I also want to show the total price of the order in the last `<p>`. You can see the calculation in the html: `{{(details.productPrijs * details.aantal)+details.extrasPrice}}` but then I get the total price for each product not the total price for all the products in that order.

So I probably have to do kinda the same calculation in my angular controller but I can't seem to get to the order.details[productPrijs]...?

Answer (score 0):

order.details[productPrijs] should be order.details.productPrijs?

getTotal function (ES5 only):

```
$scope.getProductTotal = function (details) {
  return details.productPrijs * details.aantal + details.extrasPrice;
}

$scope.getTotal = function () {
  if ($scope.orders && $scope.orders.details) {
    return $scope.orders.details
      .map($scope.getProductTotal)
      .reduce(function (total, productTotal) {
        return total + productTotal;
      });
  }
};
```

To avoid repetition (DRYness), getProductTotal can be reused in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat= "details in o.details">
  {{details.aantal}} x {{details.productTitle}}
  <div ng-if="details.extras">
   +{{details.extras}} 
   </div>
   {{getProductTotal(details)}}
 </li>     
 <p class="totalprice">{{getTotal()}} euro</p>
```

To avoid excessive computation at digest time, you can calculate totals when you query your server (if your data gets only updated that way)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new scope variable that will be the filtered array by using this syntax

```
 <li ng-repeat= "o in filteredOrders=(orders | orderBy:'-orderDate')">
```

Then create a controller method to loop through the `filteredOrders` array and total the prices

Answer (score 0):

**in your controller :**

```
getorders = angular.module('getorders', []);
getorders.controller("allorders",function($scope,$http){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    $scope.orders=[];
    $scope.getTotal=function(orders){
        return orders.reduce(function(total,detail){
            total+=(detail.productPrijs * detail.aantal)+detail.extrasPrice
        },0)
    }
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'orders').then(function (results) {
        $scope.orders = results.data;
    });
});
```

**in view :**

```
<p class="totalprice">{{getTotal(o.details)}} euro</p>
```

**Edit:** reworked (not) to please mr charlietfl

Comment: and if an order gets deleted or added? That logic doesn't belong in the request callback

Comment: quick n dirty... that's only for the logic!

Comment: I'm getting: TypeError: orders.reduce is not a function

Comment: @charlietfl, it was **NOT** to please you :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to calculate the total price in your controller. 
Something like that if I understood correctly:

```
getorders.controller("allorders",function($scope,$http){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'orders').then(function (results) {
        $scope.orders = results.data;

        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(order)) {
            total += (order.productPrijs * order.aantal) + order.extrasPrice;
        }

        $scope.orderTotal = total;
    });
});
```

The you just insert orderTotal in your HTML.

```
<p class="totalprice">{{ orderTotal  }} euro</p>
```

I didn't try it, I hope it works.